# spark not deleting temp dir after finishing job

Tags: apache-spark

On submitting a spark job I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-7cfa4c84-2d14-4666-aa7f-9dc84474fe89
```

I've got the winutils binaries installed and I've run `chmod 777` on `/tmp/hive` as per [this article](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html). I'm running spark version 2.0.0 on Windows 10 64 bit. I've tried running as admin, and double-checking that the directory actually exists (which it does).

Comment: I have the exact same issue, just by exiting spark-shell or by running any of the examples. I tried changing the working dir with --conf spark.local.dir in case it were a privileges issue, but it didn't work either. If anyone has a solution, please share.